# How do I use try except on multiple elements?

Tags: python, try-except

So I'm trying to set several values divided by other variables that could be 0, so I decided to use try except:

```
    try:
        p = pacific / float(a)
        m = mountain / float(b)
        c = central / float(c)
        e = eastern / float(d)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        p = 0
        m = 0
        c = 0
        e = 0

    print(p)
    print(m)
    print(c)
    print(e)
```

So since a b c and d could all possibly be zero, I wanted to create an instance where if p m c or e ends up being undefined as a result of a b c or d being zero, then I want to set only that one specific undefined variable (p m c or e) to 0. For example, if p m c all divide out into floats, but d is 0 and e becomes undefined, I want to return the number values of p, m, and c, but e as 0. How do I achieve this? My code above, sets p m c and e all to 0 if only a single variable among p m c or e is undefined. I know I could probably brute force this and make a try except for each of the 4 variables, but I'm looking for a way to shorten this piece of code.

Comment: Update your example to include values of the variables. Were they strings?

Comment: yes, they were strings, but either way they are floats when calculating

Comment: Yes, I did notice that from the `float()` part. Its weird that you won't add the initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check each entry, but you can do so with minimal code

```
p = pacific  / float(a) if float(a)!=0 else 0
m = mountain / float(b) if float(b)!=0 else 0
c = central  / float(c) if float(c)!=0 else 0
e = eastern  / float(d) if float(d)!=0 else 0

print(p)
print(m)
print(c)
print(e)
```

Comment: I think `a` is a string. I was fooled by that too!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to try the division and return a default.

```
def mydiv(a, b):
    try:
        return a/float(b)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

p = mydiv(pacific, float(a))
m = mydiv(mountain, float(b))
c = mydiv(central, float(c))
e = mydiv(eastern, float(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using numpy arrays, which have nice error handling capabilities and involve much less code. Division by zero produces infinity, which is easily replaced with zero.

```
import numpy as np
pmce  = np.array([1,2,3,4]) # numerator
abcd = np.array([5,6,0,8]) # denominator

with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    pmce_new = pmce/abcd
    pmce_new[np.isinf(pmce_new)] = 0

print(pmce_new)
```

Output:

```
[0.2    0.33333333     0.     0.5 ]
```